# Two different notions of maximal roots of a root system

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

There is a partial order on a root system given by $\alpha \prec \beta$ if and only if $\beta-\alpha \in R^{+}$, and Humphreys (10.4. Lemma A) proves that there is a unique maximal root with respect to this ordering.

There is another notion of maximality of a root in terms of its length: Since the reflection $\sigma_{\alpha}$ can be factored into a product of simple reflections, the length of its reduced factorization into simple roots is an invariant (and it can be determined by counting the number of positive roots that are sent to negative roots under $\sigma_{\alpha}$). So the "maximal" root under this notion is the root $\alpha \in R$ such that $\sigma_{\alpha}$ satisfying $\sigma_{\alpha}(R^{+}) = R^{-}$. I don't even know if the root that is maximal in this sense is unique.

Are these two notions related?

Comment: I'm not sure that a root with that property exists in general. There is always such an element of the Weyl group but it doesn't have to be a reflection orthogonal to a root (just generated by them). That element is unique of course and is the longest element of the Weyl group under the Bruhat order that you mention.

Comment: @Callum Good point, thank you!

Comment: To strengthen what @Callum writes: More often than not (exceptions only among $A_n, D_n$, and $E_6$) the longest element of the Weyl group is $-id$, which (except for $A_1$) is obviously not the reflection through any root. There would still be roots $\alpha$ which are "maximal" with respect to word length of $\sigma_\alpha$ written in simple reflections, but they would not satisfy $\sigma_\alpha(R^+)=R^-$. I duoubt they would be unique either. Could you maybe just check by hand and share results for $A_2, B_2$ and $G_2$?

Comment: In $A_{n - 1}$, the longest reflection (in terms of Coxeter length) is the transposition $(1 n)$ with root $e_1 - e_n = \alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_{n - 1}$.

Comment: In $B_2$, there are four reflections; two are simple and the other two both have Coxeter length $3$.  (As signed permutations, they are $(2 \ \overline{2})$ and $(1 \ \overline{2})(\overline{1} \ 2)$.)  But in $B_n$ for $n > 2$, there is a unique longest reflection $(n - 1 \ \overline{n})(\overline{n - 1} \ n)$ with root $e_{n - 1} + e_{n}$ (and how you write this in terms of simples depends on which root system you take).

Comment: For $G_2$ there are a pair of longest reflections, those corresponding to the roots $3\alpha_1 + 2 \alpha_2, 2\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ both with length $5$: $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2$ respectively, where $\sigma_i = \sigma_{\alpha_i}$. The first is the highest root but the second is not the "second highest root" or anything like that. More specifically, $2\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \leq 3\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ in the root ordering but $ \sigma_{3\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}\leq \sigma_{2\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}$ in the Bruhat ordering.

Comment: @JBL which way are you numbering your $e_i$ in the $B_n$ example? Is that the highest root? My rough calculations suggest it is but I would usually call that $e_1 + e_2$ (or $\alpha_1 +2(\alpha_2 +\cdots + \alpha_n)$ in terms of simple roots). If so can we make a conjecture that the reflection orthogonal to the highest root has maximal length even if it is not unique?

Comment: I have almost immediately found a counterexample to my conjecture. In $C_4$ the highest root gives a reflection with length $7$ but I can find a reflection which has length $11$ (the root is $\alpha_1 + 2 \alpha_2 + 2 \alpha_3 + \alpha_4$ while the highest root is $2\alpha_1 + 2 \alpha_2 + 2 \alpha_3 + \alpha_4$).

Comment: So to conclude the induced Bruhat ordering and the root ordering are not related, or at least not in a nice simple way, and there can be several roots which are all "maximal" with respect to the Bruhat ordering.

Comment: @Callum: In $G_2$, that "not second highest root" is the highest *short* root though, right? And it looks like in your $C_4$ example, that one with reflection length 11 is also the highest short root? I don't dare making the next conjecture though ...

Comment: @Callum: in $B_n$, I guess I was taking the simples to have $\alpha_1$ be either $e_1$ or $2e_1$ (I can't ever remember my B versus C) and $\alpha_2 = e_2 - e_1$, $\alpha_3 = e_3 - e_2$, ..., $\alpha_n = e_n - e_{n - 1}$.  (For those of us who think in terms of the combinatorics of signed permutations, this is roughly the most natural thing to do.)  Since $W_{B_n} = W_{C_n}$, you would expect in one root system to get the highest root and in the other root system to get the highest short root, as Torsten suggests.

Comment: (I am sure that the answer to this question is known and written down somewhere and I am embarrassed that I don't know where off the top of my head.  Sorry to the OP.)